# Simple website structure RewriteRule for PHP GET parameters

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite the examples below?

> www.domain-name.com/site-name/index.php?lang=en-us&page=home
>   www.domain-name.com/site-name/index.php?lang=en-us&page=about
>   www.domain-name.com/site-name/index.php?lang=pt-pt&page=inicio
>   www.domain-name.com/site-name/index.php?lang=pt-pt&page=sobre

To this:

> www.domain-name.com/site-name/en-us/home.html
>   www.domain-name.com/site-name/en-us/about.html
>   www.domain-name.com/site-name/pt-pt/inicio.html
>   www.domain-name.com/site-name/pt-pt/sobre.html

I managed to get the *page* parameter. This is what I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /site-name/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't know how to append .html in the end for all "*page*" parameters and regex are really not my thing, so Im having some hard time figuring out how the "-" part for the "*lang*" parameter will work. I've noticed that website gets weird when incorrect url's are typed.

Later it will have it's own domain name, but I guess changing from "**RewriteBase /site-name/**" to "**RewriteBase /**" will fix it, right?

I don't know much about it, but I think some flags are missing too (for SEO purposes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /site-name/

    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)\.html?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```