# .htaccess redirect based on country and language

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496757/simple-website-structure-rewriterule-for-php-get-parameters) about *.htacess* rules and everything works fine.
I've also found solutions to **301** redirect users based on detected language (*HTTP:Accept-Language*), but I haven't found answer to how can I redirect users from *pt-**PT***, *pt-**BR***, *en-**US*** to specific main pages:

- www.example.com/pt-pt/inicio.html
- www.example.com/pt-br/inicio.html
- www.example.com/en-us/home.html

Here is my working *.htaccess* file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  # This is for not allowing access from libwww-perl User-Agent
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
  RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

  # This is for IP Canonicalization
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^999\.999\.999\.999
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  # This is for URL Canonicalization
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  # This is from another StackOverflow question
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)\.html?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

How can I achieve that? I'm a little affraid of touching the .htaccess file...

**Edit:** Does the order of lines makes difference until *IP canonicalization*? The website is in a shared host and it hasn't passed the test on this for SEO. Also, the root PHP page is already detecting the language and I could make the redirect, but I guess *.htaccess* would be a more elegant and efficient way to do it.